# Free $\mathbb{Z}G$ module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $G$ denote a group and $\mathbb{Z}G$ the group ring. Let $F$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}G$ module over a set $X$. Why $F$ is free $\mathbb{Z}$ module over the set $\{gx|x \in X, g \in G\}$? Why is it not a free $\mathbb{Z}$ module over $X$ itself?

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand that $\Bbb Z G\cong \Bbb Z^{|G|}\not\cong\Bbb Z$ as $\Bbb Z$-modules when $|G|>1$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{Z}G \cong \mathbb{Z}^{|G|}$ because elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $\Sigma ng$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{|G|} \ncong \mathbb{Z}$ because $\mathbb{Z}$ modules are precisely abelian groups and they are not isomorphic groups. But I still do not understand the connection with my question. Kindly help me.

Comment: @Steve: A free $\Bbb ZG$-module looks like $\Bbb ZG\oplus\Bbb ZG\oplus\cdots\oplus\Bbb ZG$. Note $\Bbb Z G$ is itself the free $\Bbb ZG$-module over a singleton set $X=\{x\}$, which is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module, whereas the free $\Bbb Z$-module over a singleton $X=\{x\}$ is simply $\Bbb Z$, so my answer has *already* given you the simplest illustration of how a free $\Bbb ZG$-module on a set is not the free $\Bbb Z$-module on the set: the rank of former is bigger by a factor of $|G|$! Every case will be of this form, only multiplied by a factor of $|X|$'s size...

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}G$ is a free module over $\mathbb{Z}$, with $G$ as basis. Try proving that $F$ is (isomorphic to) a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module over $X\times G$.

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is sums of elements of $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}G$, which is the same as sums of $\{gx:g\in G, x\in X\}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.  $F$ is not a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module over $X$ (over $\{1_G\cdot x:x\in X\}$) because $X$ does not generate $F$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.